# Error serializing props returned from `getStaticProps` in "/"

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client, strapi, graphql-js

I am trying to build a NextJs blog website with Strapi+ graphql. But after following the steps given by the official strapi video source I stuck with this issue in the home.jsx file...

```
Error: Error serializing props returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: Props must be returned as a plain object from getStaticProps: `{ props: { ... } }` (received: `[object Undefined]`).
```

Here is the Home.jsx page codes:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import HomePage from "./home/home";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client";


export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    url: "http:/localhost:1337/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const GET_BLOGS = gql`
    query getBlogs {
      blogs {
        id: string
        title: string
      }
    }
  `;
  let getData = client.query({ query: GET_BLOGS });
  console.log("" + getData);

  return { props: getData.blogs };
}

export default function Home({ blogs }) {
  if (blogs) return console.log(blogs);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <HomePage />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

**Maybe dependency issue with next and strapi package.json file so here are dependencies of both:**

Nextjs package.json dependencies-

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.17",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "graphql": "^16.0.1",
    "next": "12.0.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0"
  },
```

Strapi project dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "knex": "0.21.18",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.0",
    "strapi": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-admin": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-graphql": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-i18n": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-utils": "3.6.8"
  },
"engines": {
    "node": ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x",
    "npm": "^6.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: fix typo, `http:/localhost:1337/graphql` to `http://...`

Comment: What does `console.log(getData)` output in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can check below options for your case and see if it works.

```
1. Try to do finalData = getData.json(), and then destruce it like finalData.blogs()
2. Const finalData = JSON.Stringify(getData); and then use final data.
```

> The network calls response need to be serialised in jsx, and by applying above two cases you can resolve the issue

Comment: I already tried it. but it did not work save issue occured.

Comment: Are you avle to print the data returned from graphql?

Comment: Yes, Actually, Axios has done that thing behind the scene better, and the above query works fine in Graphql localhost:1337/graphql. but whatever i try json. stringify json.parse or axios all shows same error. I rebuild entire project from scratch and feel that maybe version issue with next, graphql or stripi?? but I m new in strapi, so not sure how to solve that.

Comment: here is the query  outpur in graphql :

Comment: {
  "data": {
    "blogs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "M1 vs M1 Pro and M1 Max"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "M1 vs intel"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: It should work, not sure what is the issue here

Comment: @Santosh Is that the same output for `console.log(getData)`?